# Analysis of the function $y=x^{\frac{1}{x}}$

Tags: calculus

The graph of the function $y=x^{\frac{1}{x}}$ for positive $x$ is as shown below:

[image]

When I calculated $y$ for negative values of $x$ only some of the values between $0$ and $-1$ and only those for which $x$ is odd(whole number), were given by Excel, and they are:

[image]

If the function behaves so nicely for positive $x$, why not so nicely for negative $x$?

If $y=-x^{\frac{1}{-x}}=\frac{1}{-x^{\frac{1}{x}}}$, why don't we take the reciprocal of all the values of $y$ for positive $x$ and negate them to plot the negative X-axis?

Comment: The function is not defined for $x \le 0$ ... and, once more, Excel does not know it !

Comment: It's complex valued for $x\le0$.

Comment: @m0nhawk. It seems that you are correct. Complex values for $x<-1$.

Comment: When $x$ is negative, $x^a$ generally isn't defined, with a couple of exceptions: (1) when $a$ is an integer; (2), according to some conventions, when $a$ is a rational number whose denominator can be taken to be odd. That's because if $a = p/q$, with $q$ odd, it makes sense to write $x^a = (\sqrt[q]{x})^p$ even when $x$ is negative. Excel seems to be following these conventions.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I plotted $\Im x^{1/x}$ in *Mathematica*, it's not zero for $(-1,0)$.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does Excel do on an input of $-3/2$? And $-1.5$? It might make a very big difference whether Excel thinks $x$ is *exactly* $-3/2$, in which case it's possible to do a calculation that makes sense, or *approximately* $-3/2$, in which case there is no meaningful answer to the question.

Comment: @Dave, for both $-3/2$ and $-1.5$, excel is not giving any answer

Comment: Then probably, when you enter an integer like $-3$, it does a calculation taking into account that it's *exactly* an odd integer, but it doesn't do anything similar for $-3/2$, for which the calculation is theoretically possible. Raising to the power of $-1/3$ means taking the reciprocal of the cube root, and this is a calculation you can do with a negative number.

Answer (score 3):

The complex $\log$ map is multivalued and this forces $f$ to be multivalued for $x<0$.

$$\log(k,z)=\ln|z|+(\arg(z)+2k\pi)i,\,\,\,k\in\mathbb{Z}$$

If $z<0$, then $\arg(z)=\pi$

and therefore,

$$[z^{1/z},k]\to\exp\left(\frac{\log(k,z)}{z}\right),\,\,\,k\in\mathbb{Z}$$

consequently for negative $z$ the function is equivalent to the multivalued map:

$$[z^{1/z},k]\to\exp\left(\frac{\ln|z|+(\pi+2k\pi)i}{z}\right),\,\,\,k\in\mathbb{Z}$$

Some Maple code for verification:

```
 restart;
 f := proc (x) options operator, arrow; x^(1/x) end proc
 fn := proc (k, x) options operator, arrow;
 exp((ln(abs(x))+I*(Pi+2*k*Pi))/x) end proc
```

and now check:

```
 f(-2/3); evalc(%)
```

(3/4*I)*sqrt(2)*sqrt(3)

```
 fn(0, -2/3); evalc(%) #check using principal branch of log
```

(3/4*I)*sqrt(6)

Answer (score 2):

For negative values of $x$, Excel seems to give you an answer for $x^{1/x}$ only when it knows the exponent $1/x$ is a rational number that can be written with an odd denominator.

For example, $(-3)^{-1/3} = 1/\sqrt[3]{-3}$.

If it is doing this, then you probably won't always have a negative answer. For example, for $x = -3/2$, you'd expect to get $1/(\sqrt[3]{-3/2})^2$, which is positive.

Comment: if $x=-3/2$ then $y=\frac{1}{(\sqrt{-3/2})^3}$

Comment: That would be $x^x$, not $x^{1/x}$.

Comment: yes, you are right